# How to increment a counter inside a reduce function using dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am trying to do a JSON to JSON transformation using dataweave (for an EDI 811 mapping). My requirement is for every VEH segment (having Vehicle information) inside an HL loop, I want to start a counter from 1 to number of Vehicle records.

```html
My input format is -

[
  {
    "IDENTIFIER": "ABC",
    "HOST_ID": "XYZ",
    "BusinessKey": "11111",
    "HL0": {
      "HL0_STATE_ID": "22",
      "HL0_RPT_SYS_ID": "ABCD",
      "HL0_CO_NAIC": "11111"
    },
    "HL1": {
      "HL1_NAIC_COMP_CODE": "111111",
      "HL1_CO_ADDRESS": "AAAA BBBB CCCCC",
      "HL1_CO_CITY": "MABCD",
      "HL1_CO_STATE": "AB",
      "HL1_CO_ZIP_9": "12345"
    },
    "Details": [
       {
        "HL4": {
          "HL4_POLICY_NUM": "8767886857",
          "HL4_TRAN_CODE_ALPHA": "JGJ",
          "HL4_CYCLE_DATE_CC": "19",
          "HL4_CYCLE_DATE_YYMMDD": "200511",
          "HL4_STATE_CODE": "VV",
          "HL4_STATE_REPORTING_ID": "0000",
          "HL4_PRODUCT_CODE": "DD",
          "HL4_SUB_PRODUCT_CODE": "",
          "HL4_SENDER_ID": "",
          "HL4_POLICY_TYPE": "V",
          "HL4_PROTEUS_TRANSACTION": "00000",
          "HL4_TRAN_SUB_TYPE_CODE": "",
          "HL4_TRAN_DATE_CC": "00",
          "HL4_TRAN_DATE_YYMMDD": "000000",
          "HL4_TRAN_TIME": "00000000",
          "HL4_POL_EFF_DATE_CC": "00",
          "HL4_POL_EFF_DATE_YYMMDD": "000000",
          "HL4_POL_EXP_DATE_CC": "00",
          "HL4_POL_EXP_DATE_YYMMDD": "000000",
          "HL4_PERSON_ORG_INDIC": "1",
          "HL4_LIAB_INDIC": "",
          "HL4_AGENT_CODE": {
            "HL4_AGENT_PREFIX": "",
            "HL4_PRODUCER_AGENT": "00000"
          },
          "HL4_CANCEL_EFF_DATE": {
            "HL4_CANCEL_EFF_DATE_CC": "00",
            "HL4_XCL_EFF_DATE_YYMMDD": "000000"
          },
          "HL4_DRV_NAME": {
            "HL4_DRV_LAST_NAME": "DDDDDD",
            "HL4_DRV_FIRST_NAME_MI": "PPPPP"
          },
          "HL4_DRV_ADDRESS": "KHHKHK HJHKHKH GGGGGG RD S",
          "HL4_DRV_CITY": "IOHKHL",
          "HL4_DRV_STATE": "MB",
          "HL4_DRV_ZIP": "68686",
          "HL4_DRV_DLN": "875758865",
          "HL4_DRV_DLN_STATE": "BJ",
          "HL4_DRV_DOB_NUM": {
            "HL4_DRV_DOB_YYMMDD": "20",
            "HL4_DRV_DOB_CC": "200525"
          },
          "HL4_DRV_SEX": "",
          "HL4_VEH_EFF_DATE_NUM": {
            "HL4_VEH_EFF_DATE_CC": "00",
            "HL4_VEH_EFF_DATE_YYMMDD": "000000"
          },
          "HL4_VEH_EXP_DATE_NUM": {
            "HL4_VEH_EXP_DATE_CC": "20",
            "HL4_VEH_EXP_DATE_YYMMDD": "220423"
          }
        },
        "HL5": [
          {
            "HL5_VEH_VIN": "1BJHFJBKHJK6876868",
            "HL5_VEH_MAKE": "CDRJV",
            "HL5_VEH_CC": "19",
            "HL5_VEH_YY": "99"
          },
          {
            "HL5_VEH_VIN": "1BVNVJH68686JHG979",
            "HL5_VEH_MAKE": "JHGJGJG",
            "HL5_VEH_CC": "19",
            "HL5_VEH_YY": "92"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "HL4": {
          "HL4_POLICY_NUM": "6877578787",
          "HL4_TRAN_CODE_ALPHA": "ABC",
          "HL4_CYCLE_DATE_CC": "20",
          "HL4_CYCLE_DATE_YYMMDD": "210805",
          "HL4_STATE_CODE": "30",
          "HL4_STATE_REPORTING_ID": "0000",
          "HL4_PRODUCT_CODE": "CA",
          "HL4_SUB_PRODUCT_CODE": "",
          "HL4_SENDER_ID": "",
          "HL4_POLICY_TYPE": "V",
          "HL4_PROTEUS_TRANSACTION": "00000",
          "HL4_TRAN_SUB_TYPE_CODE": "",
          "HL4_TRAN_DATE_CC": "00",
          "HL4_TRAN_DATE_YYMMDD": "000000",
          "HL4_TRAN_TIME": "00000000",
          "HL4_POL_EFF_DATE_CC": "00",
          "HL4_POL_EFF_DATE_YYMMDD": "000000",
          "HL4_POL_EXP_DATE_CC": "00",
          "HL4_POL_EXP_DATE_YYMMDD": "000000",
          "HL4_PERSON_ORG_INDIC": "2",
          "HL4_LIAB_INDIC": "",
          "HL4_AGENT_CODE": {
            "HL4_AGENT_PREFIX": "",
            "HL4_PRODUCER_AGENT": "00000"
          },
          "HL4_CANCEL_EFF_DATE": {
            "HL4_CANCEL_EFF_DATE_CC": "00",
            "HL4_XCL_EFF_DATE_YYMMDD": "000000"
          },
          "HL4_DRV_NAME": {
            "HL4_DRV_LAST_NAME": "EE SSSSSS LLC",
            "HL4_DRV_FIRST_NAME_MI": ""
          },
          "HL4_DRV_ADDRESS": "6869800 CCCCCC DR",
          "HL4_DRV_CITY": "JFJJFJG",
          "HL4_DRV_STATE": "GK",
          "HL4_DRV_ZIP": "868875",
          "HL4_DRV_DLN": "77797968123",
          "HL4_DRV_DLN_STATE": "NM",
          "HL4_DRV_DOB_NUM": {
            "HL4_DRV_DOB_YYMMDD": "20",
            "HL4_DRV_DOB_CC": "210907"
          },
          "HL4_DRV_SEX": "",
          "HL4_VEH_EFF_DATE_NUM": {
            "HL4_VEH_EFF_DATE_CC": "20",
            "HL4_VEH_EFF_DATE_YYMMDD": "220410"
          },
          "HL4_VEH_EXP_DATE_NUM": {
            "HL4_VEH_EXP_DATE_CC": "00",
            "HL4_VEH_EXP_DATE_YYMMDD": "000000"
          }
        },
        "HL5": [
          {
            "HL5_VEH_VIN": "1GJHHKHGJGJGJG878",
            "HL5_VEH_MAKE": "JGKJGJH",
            "HL5_VEH_CC": "20",
            "HL5_VEH_YY": "15"
          },
          {
            "HL5_VEH_VIN": "1JHGJGGKG97968687",
            "HL5_VEH_MAKE": "GJJG",
            "HL5_VEH_CC": "20",
            "HL5_VEH_YY": "22"
          },
          {
            "HL5_VEH_VIN": "186876BJHGJGJ7868",
            "HL5_VEH_MAKE": "GJGKHKH",
            "HL5_VEH_CC": "20",
            "HL5_VEH_YY": "20"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My Output format JSON is as below, the VEH segments are all mapped from HL5 records in the above JSON input. in VEH01, I want to map the index/occurrence of HL5 record, so if there are 3 HL5 records with the HL4, we will get HL-VEH loop 3 times, and the VEH01 should increment from '1' for first occurrence, '2' for second occurrence and '3' for 3rd occurrence, For the next HL4-HL5 records, VEH01 should again start from "1"-

```html
{
  "TransactionSets": {
    "v003050": {
      "811": [
        {
          "Group": {
            "GS04": "..."
          },
          "Heading": {
            "020_BIG": {
              "BIG01": "...",
              "BIG02": ".."
            },
....
....
        "Detail": {
            "010_HL_Loop": [
              {
                "010_HL": {
                  "HL01": "1",
                  "HL03": "1",
                  "HL04": "1"
                },
...
...
             {
                "010_HL": {
                  "HL01": "8",
                  "HL02": "7",
                  "HL03": "5",
                  "HL04": "0"
                },
                "020_LX_Loop": [
                  {
                    "020_LX": {
                      "LX01": 1
                    },
                    "025_VEH": {
                      "VEH01": 1,             ---> This should be 1
                      "VEH02": "1BJHFJBKHJK6876868",
                      "VEH03": ..,
                      "VEH04": ..,
                      "VEH05": "..",
                      "VEH06": "CDRJV"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "010_HL": {
                  "HL01": "9",
                  "HL02": "7",
                  "HL03": "5",
                  "HL04": "0"
                },
                "020_LX_Loop": [
                  {
                    "020_LX": {
                      "LX01": 1
                    },
                    "025_VEH": {
                      "VEH01": 1,             ---> This should be 2
                      "VEH02": "1BVNVJH68686JHG979",
                      "VEH03": ..,
                      "VEH04": ..,
                      "VEH05": "..",
                      "VEH06": "JHGJGJG"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
...
...
...
                "010_HL": {
                  "HL01": "11",
                  "HL02": "10",
                  "HL03": "5",
                  "HL04": "0"
                },
                "020_LX_Loop": [
                  {
                    "020_LX": {
                      "LX01": 1
                    },
                    "025_VEH": {
                      "VEH01": 1,             ---> This should be 1
                      "VEH02": "1GJHHKHGJGJGJG878",
                      "VEH03": ..,
                      "VEH04": ..,
                      "VEH05": "..",
                      "VEH06": "JGKJGJH"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "010_HL": {
                  "HL01": "12",
                  "HL02": "10",
                  "HL03": "5",
                  "HL04": "0"
                },
                "020_LX_Loop": [
                  {
                    "020_LX": {
                      "LX01": 1
                    },
                    "025_VEH": {
                      "VEH01": 1,             ---> This should be 2
                      "VEH02": "1JHGJGGKG97968687",
                      "VEH03": ..,
                      "VEH04": ..,
                      "VEH05": "..",
                      "VEH06": "GJJG"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "010_HL": {
                  "HL01": "13",
                  "HL02": "10",
                  "HL03": "5",
                  "HL04": "0"
                },
                "020_LX_Loop": [
                  {
                    "020_LX": {
                      "LX01": 1
                    },
                    "025_VEH": {
                      "VEH01": 1,             ---> This should be 3
                      "VEH02": "186876BJHGJGJ7868",
                      "VEH03": ..,
                      "VEH04": .,
                      "VEH05": "..",
                      "VEH06": "GJGKHKH"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
```

My mapping in dataweave is as below -

```html
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json

fun toHL1(rec, HL1Hierarchy) = {
    "010_HL": {
        HL01: (HL1Hierarchy + 1) as String,
        HL03: "1",
        HL04: "1"
    },
    "110_NM1_Loop": {
        "110_NM1": {
            NM101: "..",
            NM102: "..",
            NM103: "...",
            NM108: "..",
            NM109: rec.HL1.HL1_NAIC_COMP_CODE,
        }
    },
    "210_IT1_Loop": [{
        "210_IT1": {
            IT102: 1,
            IT103: "..",
            IT104: 0
        },
        "270_DTM": [{
            DTM01: "368",
            DTM02: rec.Details.HL4.HL4_CYCLE_DATE_YYMMDD[0] as Date {
                format: "yyMMdd"
            } default "000000",
            DTM05: rec.Details.HL4.HL4_CYCLE_DATE_CC[0] as Number
        }]
    }]
}
//////********************** */
fun toOrder(rec, shipHierarchy) = {
    "010_HL": {
        HL01: (shipHierarchy + 1) as String,
        HL02: "1",
        HL03: "2",
        HL04: "1"
    },
    "110_NM1_Loop": {
        "110_NM1": {
            NM101: "..",
            NM102: "..",
            NM103: "..",
        }
    }
}
//////************************ */
fun toPack(ship, cases, ordHierarchy, indexOfPacks) = {
    "010_HL": {
        HL01: (indexOfPacks + 1) as String,
        HL02: ordHierarchy as String,
        HL03: "4",
        HL04: "1",
    },
    "110_NM1_Loop": {
        "110_NM1": {
            NM101: "..",
            NM102: cases.HL4.HL4_PERSON_ORG_INDIC,
            NM103: cases.HL4.HL4_DRV_NAME.HL4_DRV_LAST_NAME,
            NM104: cases.HL4.HL4_DRV_NAME.HL4_DRV_FIRST_NAME_MI,
            NM108: "..",
            NM109: cases.HL4.HL4_DRV_DLN
        },
        "130_N3": [{
            N301: cases.HL4.HL4_DRV_ADDRESS
        }],
        "140_N4": {
            N401: cases.HL4.HL4_DRV_CITY,
            N402: cases.HL4.HL4_DRV_STATE,
            N403: cases.HL4.HL4_DRV_ZIP
        }
    },
    "210_IT1_Loop": [{
        "210_IT1": {
            IT102: 1,
            IT103: "..",
            IT104: 0
        },
        "220_SI": [{
            SI01: "..",
            SI02: "..",
            SI03: cases.HL4.HL4_TRAN_CODE_ALPHA
        }],
        "260_REF": [{
            REF01: "IG",
            REF02: cases.HL4.HL4_POLICY_NUM[0 to 7],
        },
                            {
            REF01: "XM",
            REF02: cases.HL4.HL4_DRV_DLN_STATE,
        },
                            {
            REF01: "S3",
            REF02: "V",
        },
                            {
            REF01: "DD",
            REF03: cases.HL4.HL4_POLICY_NUM[8 to 8] default " " ++ cases.HL4.HL4_CYCLE_DATE_CC as String ++ cases.HL4.HL4_CYCLE_DATE_YYMMDD as String,
        }],
        "270_DTM": [{
            DTM01: "222",
            DTM02: cases.HL4.HL4_DRV_DOB_NUM.HL4_DRV_DOB_CC as Date {
                format: "yyMMdd"
            } default "000000",
            DTM05: cases.HL4.HL4_DRV_DOB_NUM.HL4_DRV_DOB_YYMMDD as Number
        },
        {
            DTM01: if (cases.HL4.HL4_TRAN_CODE_ALPHA == "...") "036" else "007",
            DTM02: if (cases.HL4.HL4_TRAN_CODE_ALPHA == "...") cases.HL4.HL4_VEH_EXP_DATE_NUM.HL4_VEH_EXP_DATE_YYMMDD as Date { format: "yyMMdd" } default "000000" else cases.HL4.HL4_VEH_EFF_DATE_NUM.HL4_VEH_EFF_DATE_YYMMDD as Date { format: "yyMMdd" } default "000000",
            DTM05: if (cases.HL4.HL4_TRAN_CODE_ALPHA == "...") cases.HL4.HL4_VEH_EXP_DATE_NUM.HL4_VEH_EXP_DATE_CC as Number else cases.HL4.HL4_VEH_EFF_DATE_NUM.HL4_VEH_EFF_DATE_CC as Number       
        }]
    }]
}
///////************************ */
fun toItem(ship, recItems, packHierarchy, indexOfItems) = {
    "010_HL": {
        // HL01: (4) as String,
        HL01: (indexOfItems + 1) as String,
        HL02: packHierarchy as String,
        HL03: "5",
        HL04: "0"
    // HL04: cases
    },
    "020_LX_Loop": [{
        "020_LX": {
            "LX01": 1
        },
        "025_VEH": {
            "VEH01": 1,
            "VEH02": recItems.HL5_VEH_VIN,
            "VEH03": recItems.HL5_VEH_CC as Number,
            "VEH04": recItems.HL5_VEH_YY as Number {format: "0000"},
            "VEH05": "NA",
            "VEH06": recItems.HL5_VEH_MAKE
        }
    }]
}
---
{
    //Delimiters: "*>U~",
    TransactionSets: {
        v003050: {
            "811": [{
                Group: {
                    GS04: now() as Date {
                        format: "yyMMdd"
                    },
                },
                Heading: {
                    "020_BIG": {
                        BIG01: now() as Date {
                            format: "yyMMdd"
                        },
                        BIG02: "1",
                    },
                    "100_N1_Loop": [{
                        "100_N1": {
                            N101: "..",
                            N102: "...",
                            N103: "..",
                            N104: "..."
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "100_N1": {
                            N101: "..",
                            N102: "...",
                        }
                    }]
                },
                Detail: {
                    "010_HL_Loop": payload reduce (ship, accShip=[]) -> do {
                        var shipUpd = accShip << toHL1(ship, sizeOf(accShip))
                        var HL1Hierarchy = sizeOf(shipUpd)
                        var itemHierarchy = sizeOf(shipUpd)
                        var ord = payload reduce (ship, accOrd = shipUpd) -> do {
                            var ordUpd =  accOrd << toOrder(ship, HL1Hierarchy)
                            var ordHierarchy = sizeOf(ordUpd)
                            var pack = flatten(payload.Details) reduce (cases, accPkg = ordUpd) -> do {
                                var packUpd = accPkg << toPack(ship, cases, ordHierarchy, sizeOf(accPkg))
                                
                                var packHierarchy = sizeOf(packUpd)         
                                var items = cases.HL5 reduce (recItems, accItems = packUpd) ->
                                                       accItems << toItem(ship, recItems, packHierarchy, sizeOf(accItems))
                                ---
                                items
                            }
                            ---
                            pack
                        }
                        ---
                        ord
                    }
                },
                Summary: {
                    "010_TDS": {
                        TDS01: 1
                    },
                    "110_CTT": {
                        CTT01: sizeOf(flatten(payload.Details).HL5)
 
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help with the increment and resetting of the counter for VEH01 for every H4-H5 loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using reduce then the input is an array. You can use map() to add the index to each element of the array, then use as needed.

Since the transformation of the question is too complex to attempt to modify I'll make an educated guess to make a simple example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.HL5 map (($) ++ {index: $$ + 1})
```

Input:

```json
{
    "HL5": [
          {
            "HL5_VEH_VIN": "1GJHHKHGJGJGJG878",
            "HL5_VEH_MAKE": "JGKJGJH",
            "HL5_VEH_CC": "20",
            "HL5_VEH_YY": "15"
          },
          {
            "HL5_VEH_VIN": "1JHGJGGKG97968687",
            "HL5_VEH_MAKE": "GJJG",
            "HL5_VEH_CC": "20",
            "HL5_VEH_YY": "22"
          },
          {
            "HL5_VEH_VIN": "186876BJHGJGJ7868",
            "HL5_VEH_MAKE": "GJGKHKH",
            "HL5_VEH_CC": "20",
            "HL5_VEH_YY": "20"
          }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "HL5_VEH_VIN": "1GJHHKHGJGJGJG878",
    "HL5_VEH_MAKE": "JGKJGJH",
    "HL5_VEH_CC": "20",
    "HL5_VEH_YY": "15",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "HL5_VEH_VIN": "1JHGJGGKG97968687",
    "HL5_VEH_MAKE": "GJJG",
    "HL5_VEH_CC": "20",
    "HL5_VEH_YY": "22",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "HL5_VEH_VIN": "186876BJHGJGJ7868",
    "HL5_VEH_MAKE": "GJGKHKH",
    "HL5_VEH_CC": "20",
    "HL5_VEH_YY": "20",
    "index": 3
  }
]
```

You need to identify at which point you need to apply the transformation and use the added index attribute. Maybe in between this expression: `var items = cases.HL5 /* here? */ reduce ...`

Comment: fell free to upvote too if useful ;-)